# Will a refused UK Visa based on false documents affect my Canada application?

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals, applications, study

I once applied to UK in the year 2017, the Visa was refused based on false business documents presented.  I never knew my business documents were fake. The  agent in Africa who did the business documents did a fake one for me in which the embassy confirmed from the source.

Presently I am applying for a study visa in Canada and I am willing to tell them the whole truth about my previous  refusal in UK, because I believe they automatically see my previous visa applications.

What are my chances of getting the Canada visa, will the UK previous refusal be used against me?

---

[image]

Attach is the refusal letter.  Hope this not a ban ?
If asked  by other embassy if I have a previous ban the answer should be NO,   right ?

If asked if I have a previous refusal, the answer should be Yes , right ?

I will mention the truth, if I get a denial good,  if I get the visa excellent. No harm in trying ..

Comment: You do not have a UK ban at the moment. However, in practice, paragraph 320(7B) means that any new application to the UK will automatically be refused for a period of 10 years from the date of the 2017 refusal.

Answer (score 2):

The UK and Canada are both part of the "Five Eyes" group and exchange immigration data with each other. That means (as you seem to know already) that you should assume Canada will be aware of your previous UK visa refusal. This information will certainly be taken into account when deciding on any future visa application.

> I once applied to UK in the year 2017, the Visa was refused based on false business documents presented. I never new my business documents was fake. The agent in africa who did the business documents did a fake one for me in which the embassy confirmed from the source.

It sounds like you're saying the false documents were provided by some agent you hired to apply for the UK visa, and you believed they were genuine documents. You don't say where you are more specifically than Africa, but I've certainly heard stories of such dishonest agents before, including from people in various African countries. Explaining about the dishonest agent is unlikely to help your case. Somebody else, who had a refusal after knowingly submitting false documents, could also claim the agent included them without their knowledge. The agents assessing your application (both the UK agents who rejected the past application, and Canadian agents assessing a future application) will assume that you are responsible for all contents of your application.

Nobody here can tell you for certain whether an application will be approved. That decision can only be made by the appropriate authorities on the basis of far more information than would be appropriate to post here. But visa refusals for submitting false documents are taken very seriously. Having such a refusal on your record will severely reduce your chances of being granted a visa. That doesn't mean it's completely impossible, but you should consider it very unlikely unless there are very compelling reasons to make an exception in your case. Based on what you've told us, it seems unlikely that such reasons exist.

Comment: @Raymond Please edit that information into the question, it's important.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, , the person is not a visa agent . It was an agent who helped me with the registration of the business document few years back before the visa application. I only discovered it was fake when I applied for the UK  Visa in Nigeria, Afirca. Presently I live in Europe,  schengen zone. Please i need your advice on this , should I cancel the application or I give it a try . I prefer to say the truth and be denied rather than to hide the truth and get ban.

Comment: @Raymond Particularly because Canada and UK share info, you must be scrupulously honest. Any discontinuity between what you said before and what you say now must be explained, such as how the bad documents were created...but remember that an explanation, even if true, may still result in a denied application. I agree with ChrisH that your chances seem slim, and that no one here (or anyone outside UKVI) can tell you if your application will be successful or not. Still, it's your money and your application. Whether you should cancel or not cancel is only for you to decide.